# Must declare the scalar variable "@Format"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked==false)
       {
           String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CallCenter..Loy_DispMstr (CallType, SUBFormat, Disposition, SubDisposition) values (@CallType, @Format, @Disposition, @SubDisposition)", con);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CallType" , SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedItem.Value;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SUBFormat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlFormat.SelectedItem.Value;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDisp.SelectedItem.Value;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubdisp.SelectedItem.Value;
           con.Open();
           int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();  
           Label2.Text = " Your data is been saved in the database";
           Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;

       }
       else if(flag==0 && CheckBox1.Checked==true)
       {
           String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CallCenter..Loy_DispMstr (CallType, SUBFormat,Disposition, SubDisposition) values (@CallType, @Format,@Disposition, @SubDisposition)", con);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= ddlCalltype.Text;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SUBFormat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= ddlFormat.Text;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= TextBox1.Text;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value= TextBox2.Text;

           con.Open();
           int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//error on this
           con.Close();  


       }   
   }
```

> the  error is on the executenonquery
> the  error is on the executenonquery
>
> the  error is on the executenonquery
>
> the  error is on the executenonquery

Comment: 1. Change `AddWithValue` to `Add`. 2. add `@` to the start of the parameters names. 3. You declared a parameter called `@Format` but added a parameter called `SubFormat` to your parameters collection.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Please do not provide answers as comments.  There are several negative impacts that this behavior creates.

Comment: @ZoharPeled now also error is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work for you :

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CallCenter..Loy_DispMstr (CallType, SUBFormat, Disposition, SubDisposition) values (@CallType, @Format, @Disposition, @SubDisposition)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", ddlCalltype.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", ddlFormat.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Disposition", ddlDisp.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", ddlSubdisp.SelectedItem.Value);
    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Label2.Text = " Your data is been saved in the database";
    Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;

}
else if (flag == 0 && CheckBox1.Checked == true)
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CallCenter..Loy_DispMstr (CallType, SUBFormat,Disposition, SubDisposition) values (@CallType, @Format,@Disposition, @SubDisposition)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", ddlCalltype.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", ddlFormat.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Disposition", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", TextBox2.Text);

    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//error on this
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Change `AddWithValue` to `Add`

Comment: @user31121992 Welcome brother